# How to implement EIP155 signature on Polygon?

Tags: signature, polygon, ecdsa

My understanding of EIP155 is that it encodes the chain ID into the signature's V value via the following:

`v = CHAIN_ID * 2 + 35`

This works fine on chains such as Ethereum and its testnets where the chain ID is a small number. However on some blockchains the chain ID may be much larger - for example, on Polygon the chain ID is 137, and on its Mumbai testnet the chain ID is 80001. Calculating V using this chain ID will yield a value larger than can be stored in a uint8. How are you supposed to calculate a valid EIP155 V with such large chain IDs? I thought perhaps you might need to take a modulus with the uint8 size (i.e. 256) but cannot find any reference that this is correct.